# Rails: Setting a position value in before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Playlist, Song and a PlaylistSong model.

When I add a song to a playlist, it is stored as a PlaylistSong. The PlaylistSong is a join model that includes a 'position' attribute which corresponds to the songs position in the playlist.

I would like each added song to get the position set to the last PlaylistSong's position + 1 that was added to a particular playlist.

Should I do this with a before_create method in the PlaylistSong model or is there a better way? Any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) plugin work for you? This is basically what it does automatically.